# I accidentally deleted the root partition. GParted says I have to restart

Tags: partitioning

I accidentally deleted the `root` partition using the default partition editor, the partitions just disappeared. When I open GParted, I receive the following error message :

```
Partition(s) 6, 7, 8, 9 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.
```

I want to restore the partitions because it seems that the kernel is still keeping a cached image. How can I restore the partitions (before rebooting)?

Comment: What "default partitions editor" exactly did you use?  Was it 'fdisk' or a GUI tool, and if the latter, which?  Not Gparted, apparently...

Comment: Its a GUI tool: Its called Disks simply.I have a bad feeling that if I restart the system, I'll lose the partition

Comment: MBR or gpt? Either way back up partition table before rebooting. And make sure you have working repair/live Ubuntu disk. If MBR  `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > parts_sda.txt` & save file to repair disk or other device. If gpt: `sudo sgdisk --backup=table /dev/sda` If not rebooted recover partition:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10364557&postcount=34

Comment: Write the old partition start and end down or take a picture with another device like a phone.  It'll be no fun trying to find your list in a file in a filessytem which is not in a partition any longer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Took a dump from fdisk  and restored it. Then booted using grub command line use(hd0,msdos8)  and finally restored grub. Everything works, except I can't change the partitions anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you have done all that from within the running operating system and did not click the Apply button in GParted, you may be VERY lucky, because normally deleting the root partition is not possible this way - this has to be done from a Live media with unmounted partitions. So, when you reboot everything should be as it was before. In case not, you unfortunately are lost - you only can restore the system from a backup image, which hopefully you have created before.

Comment: I didnt' do it in Gparted. It happened in the system partition editor (Disks) .  I opened GParted to check what's going on. Everything works hunky dory, except thepartitions don't show up on system editor.  They show up on GParted with an exclamation mark before them . and the error message as shown  .

Comment: By everything being okay, I mean the partitions are mounted fine. All the files are there and everything. It doesn't show up in the partition list

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee : Boot from an Ubuntu installation media, select Try Ubuntu without installing - open GParted and check whether the error messages are gone - additionally open Disks and check for the same. If everything looks okay, reboot into the Ubuntu operating system and re-check everything again. :)

Comment: You sure the partitions won't disappear when I do that. I checked somewhere and it said the kernel maintains a permanent cache of the table when the partitions are in use and refreshes on restart. 
When I open Disks, the partitions are gone, but in Gparted,they're still there.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee : You have done something you shouldn't have done, but as I say in my answer, you most probably are **lucky** that **"nothing"** happened ... so rebooting is definitely necessary ... you have no other chance ! Good chances are that after checking and rebooting everything will show up correctly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I wanted to add a note for those who stumble upon this answer.

Rebooting at this point would be the worst thing you could do. If you accidentally delete a partition, see that message ("unable to inform the kernel of the change"), and still have access to the contents of that partition, consider yourself warned that you will lose access to all of those contents when you reboot unless you first find a way to restore the partition table as it was. And since you say it is the root partition that you've deleted, you won't be able to boot into an OS without some inserting bootable media.

FIRST thing to do is to backup the contents of that disk to another disk while you still can. THEN you can try to find clever ways to restore the partition table.

If you don't find a way to restore the partition table, then you will certainly lose that partition on your next restart/boot. Though the contents will not have been physically deleted from the disk, you will have no straightforward way to access them.

Comment: Yup. I think that's what I ended up doing. I backed it up and rebooted with a partitions backup.  If I remember correctly, everything was fine. Rebooting without the backups would have been a really really stupid idea